# Centos 7 Mouse integration on Virtual Box not working

Tags: centos, virtualbox

```
Unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:\Program 
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine CentOS7Minimal.



Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program   
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
Callee: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

Mouse integration not working in Guest OS which is Centos 7.

My Host OS is Window 7.

I have installed guest additions and also I ticked sharing bidirectional.

Comment: Looks like your guest is CentOS Minimal.  Suspect you cannot have mouse integration if your guest has no GUI

Comment: The problem is not at the guest side. It's VirtualBox that's refusing to attach the iso to the guest.

Answer (score 5):

Right-click the VM from the list, click Settings, click System on the left menu, and change Pointing Device to "USB Tablet" instead of "PS/2 Mouse".

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxe01.gif `(c) https://tricks.one`

Comment: It doesn't work for rhel 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try, this in Guest. `eject /dev/sr0` no errors? As root or with sudo `mkdir /media/cdrom` with extended rights too `mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom`

```
`yum install dkms kernel-devel`
```

`yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` if not installt.

sources [Wiki centos](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox/CentOSguest)