# How do I enable a flowing transition of cursor between Windows and CentOS?

Tags: centos, windows, mouse, troubleshooting, distributions

I am currently using:
windows 10 home 64 bit
and centos 7

It is quite disturbing to my work flow every time I need to right ctrl
to get out of the virtual machine's window back to the windows' application windows be it chrome etc

How do I enable a more fluid transition without any special keys to let me in and out of CentOS ?

Comment: What virtual technology?

Comment: I am using virtual box right now

Comment: Possible duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328972/centos-7-mouse-integration-on-virtu

Answer (score 0):

If your ok with paying for a solution, you could use [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy).

Synergy allows you to seamlessly move and use a mouse between multiple operating systems without any interaction other than moving the mouse.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No, I am a college student.